# How long should my website wait before auto-suggesting possible choices?

Tags: response-time, time, autocomplete

We have an app that autosuggests various possible options based on a database query. For example if a user types 'Steve', it will find all Steves and allow them to choose the correct one. It *looks* somewhat similar to this: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

How long after the user releases the last key should we wait before the autosuggest appears?

We want to take the following things into account:

- The cost of a database query
- The speed of fast typer - we don't want them to have to wait a long time.
- The speed of slow typer - we don't want to fire a query off for every letter if the user is still typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite common to wait for the second or third keystroke, then add a pause based on the Keystroke Level Model - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke-level_model

Although if you have a very robust backend and matching system, you could just set your delay to 0 as Google does on some of its auto suggest processes.

You might also be able to do some javascript to measure the keystroke speed of the first 3 characters, then determine the delay based on that.

**EDIT** - If your matching is based around a "starts with" type query rather than a full "contains" query, you could set to zero and refine the results in browser based on the initial query as @Blam mentions below.

Answer (score 0):

As pure UX answer the cost of autocomplete should not be a factor but understand the reality of need to deliver the UX.

As a user I would want zero delay.  As I key in fast or slow the possibilities get refined instantly.

This is a UX site but as a developer I would say don't make every key stroke a database query.  Once you retrieve everything name that starts with s then you also have every name that starts with st.  As a web site it would mean hold that information in a session or a shared cache.  Or even hold that information in the client but that get a bit harder with a web client.

Comment: Down vote care to comment?

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, but I appreciate you answer. Is an immediate response *really* best though? I feel a rapidly changing autosuggest would take away from my experience as it might be a bit confusing at first.

Comment: Why would a delay be better?  Either way the auto suggest needs to be clearly distinguishable.  The common presentation is gray.  If I am typing in ste and stop to see the suggestions I don't want to wait. And suggestions in no way encumbers me from typing in steve.

Comment: I do this but in WPF where I can download to a smart client and the users love it.  As a collection in memory can really provide immediate response.  In my case a tab key does select so they can type ste tab and be done.  If they tab again it goes to the next e.g. steve thomas to steve thompson.  I use enter for commit.

Comment: I believe that the only reason to introduce any sort of latency in autocompletes is to avoid hammering your database to death. If that's not a concern (caching, fast db, local data, etc) then I think Blam's suggestion makes the most sense. The whole point of an autocomplete is to make it *faster* for a user to enter something. If they're waiting 250ms for the list to update after every keystroke you're artificially slowing them down.